# StepReg stepwise function "weights" function list numeric factor

Tags: r, regression

I am running a stepwise regression using StepReg package. I am trying to set the "weights" to a numeric value (by default they are set to NULL).

Info from package: Numeric vector to provide a weight for each observation in the input data set. Note that weights should be ranged from 0 to 1, while negative numbers are forcibly converted to 0, and numbers greater than 1 are forcibly converted to 1. If you do not specify a weight vector, each observation has a default weight of 1.

Here is my code:

```
stepwise(
  Distance ~ Vegetation+ Avg_Stem_Contacts+ Avg_Wind + Avg_Temp,
  Detection_A,
  include = NULL,
   selection = c("backward"),
   select = c("AICc"),
   sle = 0.15,
   sls = 0.15,
   weights = NULL,
   best = NULL)
```

I have tried using:
weights=c("#") and
weights=#

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible subset of your data?

Comment: Here is a reproducible example with the `mtcars` dataset. `StepReg::stepwise(
  mpg ~ wt,
  mtcars,
  include = NULL,
  selection = c("backward"),
  select = c("AICc"),
  sle = 0.15,
  sls = 0.15,
  weights = rnorm(32, .5, .15),
  best = NULL)` Notice that I made the length of the weights vector the same length as the original dataframe.